# Remote Action not working in safari browser?

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, salesforce-id, remote-action

I have remote Action in javascript which is working in all browsers but not in safari browser. Here is the code snippet below .

i have table with delete action,when i click the delete link ,it will open a popup(popuppanel) which contains "ok button"&"cancel button". if i click the ok button it will call the java script method("popupclose"),which further calls the remote action method.This remote action working fine in all browsers except safari .

```
<apex:commandLink onclick="popupopen('{!u.contact}');" rerender="none">                                                                         <apex:param name="param1" value="{!u.contact}" assignTo="{!UsId}" />                                                                         </apex:commandLink>

  <div id="popupPanel" style="display:none" class=""> 
    <div class="dialog-confirm">
      <apex:form >                                     
        <center>   <br/><br/>
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.cancel}" onclick="popupclose();return false;" />
      <apex:inputHidden value="{!Usid}" id="theHiddenInput"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.ok}" onclick="popupclosendel();"/> </center> 

 <apex:actionfunction name="refreshdiv1" action="{!staffrefresh}"    </apex:form>  </div>                                                                        
  </div>


 function popupclosendel()
                {
                   alert('coem');
                   var theDialog = $("#popupPanel").dialog({modal: true, maxWidth: 700,resizable: false, draggable: false, autoOpen: false});
                   theDialog.dialog("close");
                   alert('coem23');  





               Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(

                   '{!$RemoteAction.deletecontroller.remotedodelete}',

                    delid,                  
                    function(result, event){

                        if (event.status) 
                        {
                        alert(event.status);
                            refreshdiv1();



                        } 
                    }, 
                    {escape: true})
                );

            }
```

Comment: In http://jshint.com/, the JavaScript you have posted has an undefined variable `delid` and a spurious `)` on line 29. Start by fixing those.

Comment: Mr.Keith its not an undefined variable it stores id which record i want to delete

Comment: OK so where in the code you posted is its value set?